# why can't subset data frame by some keys?

Tags: r

such data frame as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(yr = rep(2000:2017,each=46),
                 dayorder = rep(seq(1,365,8),time=18),
                 fid = rep(1:46,time=18),
                 Value = runif(46*18)
                 )
```

when I sieve by keys:

```
df[which(dayorder==9),]
      yr dayorder fid      Value
2   2000        9   2 0.3424053
48  2001        9   2 0.6639720
94  2002        9   2 0.5530076
140 2003        9   2 0.9757845
.....
```

When use 'yr' key ,report error:

```
df[which(yr==2001),]
Error in which(yr == 2001) : object 'yr' not found
```

same error by 'fid' key"

```
df[which(fid==2),]
Error in which(fid == 2) : object 'fid' not found
```

but df$yr is existed:

```
df$yr
  [1] 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000
 .....
```

What's the problem of data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `df$` before the column name, in the first case you don't get an error probably because `dayorder` is a variable defined in your environment.

It should've thrown an error like the others.

```
df[which(df$dayorder==9),] # or df[df$dayorder==9,]
```

When I call like this `df[which(df$dayorder==9),]` I get:

> Error in which(dayorder == 9) : object 'dayorder' not found

Another solution using `with`, avoids too many `df$` (also note you can remove `which()`:

```
with(df, df[dayorder==9, ])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a `tidyverse` as well

```
library(tidyverse)
filter(df, yr == 2001)
```

Comment: or base R: `subset(df, yr == 2001)`

Comment: Yes of course...but IMO should be included in the other answer as a `baseR` solution ;)